# ExecutorService, newFixedThreadPool and setPrioirty

Tags: java, multithreading

Do the setPrioirty method works the same on newFixedThreadPool and as on regular threads?

tnx!

Comment: ExecutorService doesn't have setPriority method, does it?

Answer (score 2):

By default a `ThreadPoolExecutor` will use `Executors.defaultThreadFactory()`, which in turn will set all `Thread`'s within the executor to the `NORM_PRIORITY`.

If you want to alter the attributes of the `Thread`'s within the executor you need to provide your own `ThreadFactory` where you can specify thread priority, group, name and so on.

Take a look at [the javadoc for ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The threads in all the thread pools are the same things. If you do `Thread.currentThread().setPriority(...)` while running inside the thread pool, it will do exactly the same thing as in any other Thread.